# Charity scammer low life

Tags: proper-nouns

What would you call someone, with money, who attends an all inclusive  fund-raiser, refuses to pay the attendance fee, and sends his girlfriend up to the bar all night to get him goblets of wine while he listens to the band?  BTW, the GF paid up her end of things.

Comment: If he was at a party illegitimately, then he is a *gatecrasher*. If he was there just because the booze was free, he is a *cheapskate*, and possibly an *alcoholic*. If he sent the GF to the bar instead of going for himself because it would be an inconvenience and cause him to miss some of the music, he's *selfish* or *self-centered*.  If the GF recognizes all this, he may soon be a *single* party-crashing self-centered cheapskate. But having said all that.... no one says *goblet* any more.

Comment: I'm not trying to be flippant, but maybe **asshole**.

Comment: He's just a garden-variety *jerk*.

Comment: A *freeloader*.

Comment: Well, if we're using colloquialisms, how about __douche__?

Comment: @DanBron Dave theBozo didn't specify the nature of the charity event, perhaps it was some variety of 'Ye Olden Days' with jousting and quaffing? Or he was being very specific that the wine came in https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=paris+goblet+wine+glass&sa=X&espv=2&biw=670&bih=597&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ved=0ahUKEwjW1JGC_7bNAhUmKsAKHd-0AwkQ7AkIZw Paris Goblets rather than Flutes https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=paris+goblet+wine+glass&sa=X&espv=2&biw=670&bih=597&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ved=0ahUKEwjW1JGC_7bNAhUmKsAKHd-0AwkQ7AkIZw#tbm=isch&q=flute+wine+glass :)

Comment: Considering the deplorable ethics and egregious motives of most "charities", I call it tit for tat.

Answer (score 5):

Ligger

From [UrbanDictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ligger):

> An individual who **attends parties**, openings, social gatherings and events **with the sole intention of obtaining free food and drink** - an arch blagger.
>
> Popularised by the NME in the early nineties and possibly with it's entomological roots in the fishing term for "baited line".

Comment: OK, I've done that.

Comment: Awesome. Comment withdrawn, downvote reversed, upvoted.

Comment: Presumably the line is baited with insects, since it is apparently an entomological root.